# Avoid Toolstripmenu close on items or Dropdownitem selected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstripmenu

I have Toolstrip menu items. It is having two level of menu items. How to avoid close functionality of Toolstrip menu item when clicks on level 2 menu item and retains the previous one.

Example,
[image]

Comment: do you have `ToolStripMenuItem1.DropDown.AutoClose = true?`

Comment: Yes, if I set AutoClose to false still level 2 items is closing

Comment: Am I correct in saying you want to be able to click an item in menu2 and have it select the item (put a checkmark beside it) but not close it? So after selecting say `SubItem 5.1`, menu1 and menu2 remain open?

Comment: Yes, Capn Jack you are correct, after selecting SubItem 5.1, menu 1(level 1 menu items) and menu 2 (level 2 subItem) should not close and it should remain open only

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to specify closing behaviour for the drop down to not close on item click. Try this:

```
toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDown.Closing += toolStripDropDownButton1_Closing;

private void toolStripDropDownButton1_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: e.cancel = true is to avoid closing the toolstripmenu item for first level, still if I click on level two menu items (sub menu items), sub menu items are closing and level 1 menu items are remain open.